# Display light on Notification fired

Tags: android, notifications, light

I want to display light when notification fires in android

i have try with below code but the screen not displays light

```
if(isBlink) {
        notification.ledOffMS=25; 
        notification.ledOnMS=100;   
        notification.ledARGB=Color.RED; 
        notification.flags=notification.flags|Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your code and logic inside. But following questions may help you to debug.

1. How do you trigger isBlink ? Is this through some signal handler ?
2. How notification parameters gets acknowledged once set ? I suppose you are using some timer or loop logic.

Comment: 1) isBlink is boolean and it is true if i want light on notification 2) yes i get notification but i am not getting Light on notification

Answer (score 0):

Try to receive this notification with the screen off.. I think google have this requirement to show lights on the led.

Comment: Or try to shut down the screen after receive the notification.. it works for me in my N1